# Android - onOnCreateOptionsMenu not called through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I've currently a activity which has the lauchMode **singleTop** and a **service** which creates a Notification which opens the activity onclick.
The activity calls a function and while the function is working a refresh button of the **optionsmenu** will be set as progressbar.

To do that I save the menu and the menuItem object in the onOptionsMenuCreate function.
The problem now is that if I close the application completely and click the notification of the service, the applications opens and a NullException appears, beaucse the onOptionsMenuCreate event is not called, when the application is launched through a intent from the service. So the variables are null.
It works fine, when the application is not closed and can just be resumed.

**Here is my code (simplified):**

Intent (for the notification):

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction("START_FOO");
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
```

OnCreate() (MainActivity):

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("START_FOO")) {
        foo();
    }
```

onNewIntent() (MainActivity):

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("START_FOO")) {
        foo();
    }
```

onOptionsMenuCreate() (MainActivity):

```
    this.refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    this.menu = menu;
```

foo() (MainActivity):

```
// here comes a NullException, if the application starts through the intent. (only start - resuming works fine through the intent)
refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.menu_refresh_progress);
```

I've debugged a lot, so I can say that the onCreate function will be called, but the onOptionsMenuCreate() Event not.

- Start application without intent -> works fine
- Resume application without intent -> works fine
- Start application through intent -> OnOptionsMenuCreate not called
- Resume application through intent -> works fine

P.S.:
I hope my English has been good enough, so someone can understand my problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is only called once, when the options menu is displayed. In your case, the options menu hasn't yet been displayed which is why you are getting an exception.

Instead use a static `boolean` variable in your application and set it to `true` when the application is started via notification `Intent`. Then, in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` you can check the state of the `boolean` variable and adjust the menu content appropriately.

The method `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called everytime the menu is shown to the user, so that is the place where you should do dynamic menu adjustments.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it with onPrepareOptionsMenu() but it still works not through intent. OnCreate is called and then foo(), but onPrepareOptionsMenu doesn't get called.

Comment: If I move my phone so it switches in the landscape mode, onCreate gets called, but inPrepareOptionsMenu not -> again nullPointerException.

Comment: No, you misunderstood my post. Do not rely on `refreshItem` being set correctly when you start the app via `Notification`. You should just set a `boolean` variable to `true` when the notification is used. That's it. `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, when called, should call `setActionView()` appropriately based on the value of the `boolean` variable.

Comment: My problem is, that I need to have access to the target menu item (refreshItem), so I can use the refresh button as progressbar later.
This is the reason why I try to save an instance of the menu and the refresh Button (refreshItem) as variable.
Do you have an idear how function foo() can get access to the refresh button?

Comment: I don't understand how a menu item can be used as a progress bar, but anyway, the menu item '''doesn't exist''' until the clicks on it, so you cannot get access to it until the user opens the options list.

Comment: A circular progressbar: http://www.michenux.net/android-refresh-item-action-bar-circular-progressbar-578.html
So I can't just create it manually?

Comment: In that tutorial you can see that in method `setRefreshActionButtonState()` there is a check for `optionsMenu != null`. This prevents a `NullPointerException` if the options menu has not yet been created. Your problem is that you will need to wait until Android creates the options menu for you. You cannot create it manually. You could try to move the call to `foo()` from inside `onCreate()` to inside `onResume()`. Perhaps by then the options menu will have been created.

Comment: Hm, no onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu are not called before onResume() calls foo().

Comment: You could try delaying the call to `foo()`. Try posting a `Runnable` to a `Handler` using a delay of like 5 seconds, and check if the options menu has been created by then. Sorry I don't have time to try all this myself.